# How to create azure backup policy using CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I can't find a way to create my custom backup policy via CLI https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/backup/policy?view=azure-cli-latest

However, this can be done via REST API call https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-arm-userestapi-createorupdatepolicy

Comment: did you try `az backup policy set`?

Comment: @4c74356b41 i didn't. because docs description says "Update the properties of the backup policy"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it supports, but the official doc is missing instructions, also the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/backup/protectionpolicies/createorupdate) indicates the `create` and `update` uses the same api.

[image]

You could try the command as below, it works fine on my side.

```
az backup policy set --policy '{
  "name": "testpolicy3",
  "properties": {
    "backupManagementType": "AzureIaasVM",
    "instantRpRetentionRangeInDays": 2,
    "protectedItemsCount": 0,
    "retentionPolicy": {
      "dailySchedule": {
        "retentionDuration": {
          "count": 180,
          "durationType": "Days"
        },
        "retentionTimes": [
          "2019-07-09T07:30:00+00:00"
        ]
      },
      "monthlySchedule": {
        "retentionDuration": {
          "count": 60,
          "durationType": "Months"
        },
        "retentionScheduleDaily": null,
        "retentionScheduleFormatType": "Weekly",
        "retentionScheduleWeekly": {
          "daysOfTheWeek": [
            "Sunday"
          ],
          "weeksOfTheMonth": [
            "First"
          ]
        },
        "retentionTimes": [
          "2019-07-09T07:30:00+00:00"
        ]
      },
      "retentionPolicyType": "LongTermRetentionPolicy",
      "weeklySchedule": {
        "daysOfTheWeek": [
          "Sunday"
        ],
        "retentionDuration": {
          "count": 12,
          "durationType": "Weeks"
        },
        "retentionTimes": [
          "2019-07-09T07:30:00+00:00"
        ]
      },
      "yearlySchedule": {
        "monthsOfYear": [
          "January"
        ],
        "retentionDuration": {
          "count": 10,
          "durationType": "Years"
        },
        "retentionScheduleDaily": null,
        "retentionScheduleFormatType": "Weekly",
        "retentionScheduleWeekly": {
          "daysOfTheWeek": [
            "Sunday"
          ],
          "weeksOfTheMonth": [
            "First"
          ]
        },
        "retentionTimes": [
          "2019-07-09T07:30:00+00:00"
        ]
      }
    },
    "schedulePolicy": {
      "schedulePolicyType": "SimpleSchedulePolicy",
      "scheduleRunDays": null,
      "scheduleRunFrequency": "Daily",
      "scheduleRunTimes": [
        "2019-07-09T07:30:00+00:00"
      ],
      "scheduleWeeklyFrequency": 0
    },
    "timeZone": "UTC"
  },
  "resourceGroup": "joywebapp",
  "tags": null,
  "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupPolicies"
}' --resource-group 'joywebapp' --vault-name 'joyvault'
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for this. Is there a valid reason for create and update to share the same API? I personally find it confusing

Comment: @letthefireflieslive Not sure, but in Azure, many APIs for different services are like this.